# Lightning web component slot is not working inside select?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to create a simple lightning web component that wraps a `<select>` element, using an [unnamed slot](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_slots) to populate the options. However, the options are not being rendered. If I inspect the generated DOM elements, it is just rendering `<slot></slot>` as text inside the select element. If I move the slot outside of the select element, the slot works as expected.

This is the template for the component:

```
<template>
    <select>
        <slot></slot>
    </select>
</template>
```

And this is how I'm trying to use it:

```
<c-select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
</c-select>
```

Here is a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Tkmfs0neW/edit)

Any thoughts on why this isn't working or how I could work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done. Elements that are slotable need to be able to be attached to a shadow dom. You can see the list [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow).

You would be better off building a select list component that accepts a list of options and using a for:each to loop through them in the child component.